# How could you have controllers communicate with each other?

Tags: control, c++, webots

I have been attempting to have two controllers be able to access information from each other in a way that is similar to object-oriented programming in UNITY, however, I have constantly had problems getting it to work. I always get a similar error of:

```
Exo_controller.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
Exo_controller.cpp:22:5: error: expected primary-expression before 'public'
   22 |     public static double dist;
      |     ^~~~~~
Exo_controller.cpp:23:5: error: 'dist' was not declared in this scope
   23 |     dist = distance[1] -> getValue();
      |     ^~~~
Error 1
```

Could someone explain if it is even possible to have something like object-oriented programming and if not is there anyther way I could simulate this is Webots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Webots it is not possible to access device values from another robot controller and each controller is running in its own process.
See also this question: [read-device-value-from-another-robot-controller-in-webots](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24034/read-device-value-from-another-robot-controller-in-webots).

So if in your controller program you are trying to get the devices of another robot that it is not the one associated with the current controller instance it won't work.

However, you have some other options to make two Webots controllers communicate with each other:

1. use the [Emitter](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/emitter)/[Receiver](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/receiver) mechanism to send data from one robot/controller the other one
2. for single values you could also use the [`Robot.data`](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) field to store the data to share and read it in the other controller program using the [Supervisor](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor) API

Not specific to Webots, you can also use any standard inter-process communication mechanism (files, sockets, shared memory, etc.).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*

Comment: Thank you very much for the responce, I will try looking into recievers/emitters to see if I could use those!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to *Robotics*, Jonathan Ariel Callejas. You haven't provided your code, but I believe the problem you're having is with [variable scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Levels_of_scope).

In your case, your error suggests you're trying to make a `public` variable that lives inside a method:

> **In function** 'int main(int, char**)':  [...] **public** static double dist;

If the variable is defined inside `main`, then it can't be public because its scope is limited to `main`. (Note: It's *possible* to make a "global" variable, but global variables are never the right answer.)

The compiler is complaining because you're trying to make `public static double dist` inside `main`, and it's essentially invalidating that line of code and trying to compile the rest. But, because the declaration isn't valid, when it tries to evaluate the line that uses `dist`, it doesn't know what `dist` is and so also throws the second error:

> error: 'dist' was not declared in this scope

Easy solution should be to just remove the `public` keyword, but you can also remove the `static` keyword because `main` should be the "outer-most" method; it won't go out of scope (and `dist` won't get destructed) until the program terminates.

Now, none of this really goes to your comment

> I have been attempting to have two controllers be able to access information from each other in a way that is similar to object-oriented programming in UNITY

Unity is C#, and you're writing C++ code, and you can 100% do object-oriented code in both. In C# you can just plop everything in a file and be done with, but in C++ everything has to be declared before you can use it. Typically this is done with a [header file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=msvc-170), where you might define your class:

```
public class MyController
{
    public:
        float my_public_float;
        void DoSomethingNeat(float operand);
    private:
        float my_private_float;
};
```

You then go wherever you've got your `main` and would include the header, which should generally have the same name as the class inside it, so something like `#include<MyController.h>`. This tells your program that there is such a thing as a class called `MyController`, that it has a public float called `my_public_float`, and a method called `DoSomethingNeat` that takes a single `float` as an input, but doesn't return anything.

It doesn't tell the program *what* those things are, just that they exist. This is kind of the beauty of the header file - you can tuck your definitions away somewhere else, and as long as you don't change the header file, you don't need to rebuild the main program because the *interfaces* to that class haven't changed.

Then you'd make a `.cpp` file that actually defines what the class is. That `.cpp` file would also `#include<MyController.h>`, and might look something like:

```
#include<MyController.h>
#include<iostream> // For std::cout
#include<string> // For std::to_string

void MyController::DoSomethingNeat(float operand)
{
    std::cout<<"I was passed: "<<std::to_string(operand)<<std::endl;
}
```

Any variables that are part of the controller should be made part of the controller class, as `public` or `private` depending on whether something outside the class should be able to access it or not, and you can do the same with methods; they can be public/private as well.

All the other object-oriented concepts from Unity/C# apply - inheritance, polymorphism, etc. The syntax is a little different, but you just google the term and "c++" and should get to somewhere like [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com) that explains how to do it in C++.

I'd highly recommend reading some introductory C++ material to familiarize yourself with how concepts like these are implemented in the language.